# Automatically synchronize Java servlet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin framework and everything is setup fine using the Book of Vaadin. When I alter source code it automatically builds and synchronizes the server which I can see in the Server tab, however when I refresh my browser window nothing is changed.

The only time when I can see the change is when I select my module in the Server tab and choose Clean Module Working Directory in the right-click menu.

I have looked everywhere in Eclipse, but there must be a way where this is not needed or is done automatically, because it's somewhat tedious. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not Eclipse which is responsible for this. It's the server plugin and the server itself which is responsible for this. So, which one are you using?

Comment: As per your [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802585/clean-working-directory-of-tomcat-in-eclipse), you appear to be using Tomcat. Well, I've answered exactly this question over there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Which browser are you using? The Eclipse built-in browser (based on IE, I think) is not the best at noticing changes to the application.

Anyway, try appending "?restartApplication" after your URL to force restarting the app.

Comment: A second interesting URL parameter is ?debug which will open a debugging window in the browser. More info [in the book](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.debug-production-modes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, before i finished reading book of Vaadin. In my case it was because of session, i just add close listener for mainWindow:

```
mainWindow.addListener(new Window.CloseListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
            getMainWindow().getApplication().close();
        }
    });
```

It will close old session when F5 is pressed, try it!