# Clean Working directory of Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

When I work in on an servlet application in Eclipse, I have to choose Clean Working Directory in the server tab of Eclipse for the changes to be visible in the browser. Is there any way to make sure that I only have to build my servlet and the changes are immediately visible?

Answer (score 5):

Doubleclick the Tomcat entry in *Servers* view, go to the *Publishing* section and select *Automatically publish when resources change*.

[image]

It by the way won't happen *that* "immediately". It might take around 3 seconds, you should see this activity in server logs. Although a slow starter, but Glassfish publishes in a subsecond. You may consider it instead for fast development.

Answer (score 1):

Honesty, i do not think this is possible.

It is like programming in javascript and there is no way to see the result without clearing the browsers cache and reloading the page.

Comment: Ah, thank you. If you put it that way it actually makes a lot of sense :-)